# Create a hostPath persistent volume with kube client

Tags: go, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am using the go k8s kube client . I am trying to create a persistent volume in my cluster . I want to use the hostPath type. However I cannot find any documentation about how to do that in go . I have the following code

```golang
vl := v1.PersistentVolume{

        Spec: v1.PersistentVolumeSpec{
            //VolumeMode: v1.PersistentVolumeMode(),

            StorageClassName: "manual",
            AccessModes: []v1.PersistentVolumeAccessMode{
                "ReadWriteMany",
            },
            Capacity: v1.ResourceList{
                v1.ResourceName(v1.ResourceStorage): resource.MustParse("2Gi"),
            },
        },
    }

    vl.Name = "golang-demo-storage"
```

If i try to create the above persistent volume as it is I get an error saying `PersistentVolume "golang-demo-storage" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type` which makes sense since I have to define a type

However I cannot find any documentation about where in the struct to actually define the hostpath.

Do you have any reference that would help me ?

Comment: `hostPath` volumes aren't really persistent; if a pod gets recreated on a different node, or if a node gets destroyed by something like the cluster autoscaler, you'll lose (or at least misplace) the content.  Do you actually need to manually create the PersistentVolume?

Comment: I need to manually create a persistent volume. For my use case irun my depployments on a specific node

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am still learning so it is helpful

Comment: `hostPath` is when you **only** have **one** node in the cluster, e.g. when using Minikube. Or use `DaemonSet` that use the same path on each node.

Comment: @Jonas for my use case i only use one node

Answer (score 3):

So i was looking at the wrong fields. The field i hav to look at is the `PersistentVolumeSource` at the `PersistentVolumeSpec`. Here is the snippet of the code that worked for me

```golang
    ctx := context.TODO()
    vl := v1.PersistentVolume{

        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "PersistentVolume"},
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: name,
        },

        Spec: v1.PersistentVolumeSpec{
            //VolumeMode: v1.PersistentVolumeMode(),

            StorageClassName: "manual",
            AccessModes: []v1.PersistentVolumeAccessMode{
                "ReadWriteMany",
            },
            Capacity: v1.ResourceList{
                v1.ResourceName(v1.ResourceStorage): resource.MustParse("2Gi"),
            },
            PersistentVolumeSource : v1.PersistentVolumeSource{
                HostPath: &v1.HostPathVolumeSource{
                    Path: "/demo",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    _ , e := clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().Create(ctx , &vl , metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

I had to define a `PersistentVolumeSource` field and in its initialization i passed the host path configuration i needed